# Mongo DB: Append a value to a nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I think there might be better ways to store data but the app I am working on has some data stored like this.

I have a document with nested arrays. In this particular example, would it be possible to append a new element "value3" to an array inside products whose "productId" matches the condition. So, basically look for productId and append "value3" to the array which has matching "productId".

I am just learning about MongoDB so if you can provide some suggestions for changing schema, even that would be very helpful.

P.S. Not sure if it helps but I am using node.js

```
{"_id":
    {"$oid":"601baf0e5c307422c0fa958c"},
    "sale":"Test Sale",
    "products":[
      [
        ["productId","value1","value2"],
        ["productId","value1","value2"]
      ],
      [
        ["productId","value1","value2"],
        ["productId","value1","value2"]
      ],
      [
        ["productId","value1","value2"],
        ["productId","value1","value2"]
      ]
    ],
    "collectionProducts":["id","id","id"]
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example simulating data. It's not necessary real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
 db.store.update({},{$push:{"products.$[].$[k]":"value3"}},{ arrayFilters: [{ k:'productId' }]})
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I have one more question though. Now, I wanted to find array containing matching "productId" in the same document as matching "sale". I didn't find much in the mongo documentation regarding this.

Comment: [link to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66058186/mongo-db-find-nested-array-value)