# Mongo DB: Find nested array value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working with node.js and trying to find array containing matching "productId" in the same document as matching "sale". I didn't find much in the mongo documentation regarding this.

```
{"_id":
    {"$oid":"601baf0e5c307422c0fa958c"},
    "sale":"Test Sale",
    "products":[
      [
        ["productId","value1","value2"],
        ["productId","value1","value2"]
      ],
      [
        ["productId","value1","value2"],
        ["productId","value1","value2"]
      ],
      [
        ["productId","value1","value2"],
        ["productId","value1","value2"]
      ]
    ],
    "collectionProducts":["id","id","id"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mi5zryktrv6)

```
db.collection.find({
  "sale": "Test Sale",
  products: {
    "$elemMatch": {//As you have nested arrays
      "$elemMatch": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "$in": [
            "abc"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

It's better to have better schema.